# How to reload new data to UITable when one row data is deleted or updated in swift IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So for I've a UITableView in which I'm showing comments which is fetch from my localhost DB, when a user post comment it's send to localhost and store there and it the same time I reload table and the comment is shown it the time but when a user delete a comment or update a comment then in the DB data is actually deleted or updated but my tableview is not reloading with new data till I close the view and open it again.
following is my code.
This my delete comment code:

```
  @objc func deleteComment(){
   ProgressHUD.show("Wait Deleting", interaction: false)
    customView.removeFromSuperview()
    var commentArray : Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
    commentArray["commentId"] = self.getCommentId
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comment/delete");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
   request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
    guard let httpbody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: commentArray, options: []) else { return }
   request.httpBody = httpbody
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        // print out response object
        //  print("response = \(response)")
        //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
                if parseJSON["delete"] != nil{
                    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.alertDeleted()

                }else {
                    if parseJSON["error"] != nil{
                        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        print(parseJSON["error"] as Any)

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This is delete comment alert.

```
 public func alertDeleted(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Comment Deleted:",    message: "Press Ok to continue.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (_) in
       self.showMatchCommentsApiCall()

    }
    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is update comment code.

```
 @objc func updateComment(){
    ProgressHUD.show("Wait Upating", interaction: false)
    updateCommentView.removeFromSuperview()
    var commentArray : Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
    commentArray["commentId"] = self.getCommentId
    commentArray["updatedComment"] = textView.text
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comment/update");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
    guard let httpbody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: commentArray, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpbody
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        // print out response object
        //print("response = \(response)")
        //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
                if parseJSON["update"] != nil{
                    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.alertCommentUpdated()
                    self.showMatchCommentsApiCall()
                    return
                }else {
                    if parseJSON["error"] != nil{
                        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        print(parseJSON["error"] as Any)

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

My `ShowMatchCommentsApiCall()` function.

```
    public func showMatchCommentsApiCall(){
    ProgressHUD.show("Please Wait", interaction: false)
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/matchComments/\(getMatchId)") else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }
        do{
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                dataResponse, options: [])
            // print(jsonResponse) //Response result
            guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                return
            }
            //print(jsonArray)
            for comments in jsonArray{

                guard let commentID = comments["commentId"] as? Int else { return }
                guard let userID    = comments["userId"] as? Int else { return }
                guard let userName  = comments["userName"] as? String else { return }
                let userImgUrl = comments["userImg"] as? String
                if userImgUrl != nil{
                    self.commentsUserImgUrl.append(userImgUrl!)
                }else {
                    self.commentsUserImgUrl.append("nil")
                }
                guard let commentMessage = comments["comment"] as? String else { return }
                self.commentId.append(commentID)
                self.commmentsUserId.append(userID)
                self.commentsUserName.append(userName)
                self.comments.append(commentMessage)

            }


        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.MatchScoreTable.reloadData()
            ProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: please also post the code for table view delegates. where are you reloading the tableview?

Comment: I'm reloading table in the showMatchCommentsApiCall function please have a look at it again.

Comment: MatchScoreTable.delegate = self
        MatchScoreTable.dataSource = self

Comment: Don't call API `showMatchCommentsApiCall() ` when you delete or update data. Just take index of that record and do necessary thing `OR` if you want to call API then `removeAll` array data at start of API call and also make sure you `reloadData()` in API call `success`

Comment: By remove array data you mean to empty all the arrays to which I append data in showMatchCommentApiCall(). Secondly you mean I should call reload data function before catch block?

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint by removing array data before Api call in showMatchCommentsApiCall  it works, and if I'm not wrong the previous values in these arrays are still there till I don't empty it in this function after reloading which may be the cause of it.Thanks

Comment: @HidayatUllah have you call `reloadData()` after removing `Array`?

Comment: I call it after Api call because my new data come from DB. it works but some time I'm getting the following error 0x10f817b6e <+10>: jae    0x10f817b78               ; <+20> Thread 4:signal SIGABORT while deleting or updating but not always  sometime deletion and updating work normally but some time above error what would be the cause of this.

Answer (score -1):

After deleting or updating data just call a `UITableView` method `reloadData`

Syntax is as follows :

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: remove reload method from dispatch)async.

Comment: Call it before task.resume in ShowMatchCommentsApiCall()

Comment: Again have a look I'm calling it before task.resume()

Comment: By removing it from dispatch.main it give me thread that this method should be call in main thread.

Answer (score -1):

**STEP 1.** :`self.commentsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)`

**STEP 2.** : `self.tableView.deleteRows(at:[indexPath],with:UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)`

**STEP 3.** : `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: What about update comment and I'm not updating the whole cell I only update comment text.

Comment: @HidayatUllah for update you need to take index of cell and by using it you need to assign new object to your array using index